# Key event detecting in grid - wxPython

Tags: python-3.x, events, text, wxpython, wxgrid

I created a grid using wxPython and I need to monitor the data inserted by the user into one of the cells in my grid. I need to have an event due to every key press in the keyboard (like EVT_KEY_DOWN) and I can't find a way to do that.
Right now I need to use a grid for this purpose so the solution must be something that can be integrated into wx.grid.

I tried to use GridCellEditor but it only gives the first key.
Is there a way to integrate TextCtrl into a grid's cell or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, unless told differently, a grid is a collection of TextCtrl's, so the key is to bind `wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN` to them.
Here is one way to do it:
Note: I have added a few different element types for demonstration purposes.
Hopefully this is all that you require.

```
import wx
import wx.grid as gridlib
class MyForm(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "A key detecting grid", size=(1000,300))
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.grid = gridlib.Grid(panel)
        self.grid.CreateGrid(10, 8)
        self.grid.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.OnKeyPress) #Required for initial key press
        self.grid.Bind(gridlib.EVT_GRID_EDITOR_CREATED, self.onEditorCreated) # For subsequent key presses

    # -- Additional bits only for demonstration of isolating Text fields

        # Boolean field dislays as a CheckBox
        crbool = wx.grid.GridCellBoolRenderer()
        cebool = wx.grid.GridCellBoolEditor()
        self.grid.SetCellRenderer(1, 1, crbool)
        self.grid.SetCellEditor(1, 1, cebool)
        # Choice field
        cechoice = wx.grid.GridCellChoiceEditor(['Choice 1','Choice 2','Choice 3'], allowOthers=False)
        self.grid.SetCellEditor(1, 2, cechoice)
        #Load special fields
        self.grid.SetCellValue(1, 1, '1')
        self.grid.SetCellValue(1, 2, 'Choice 2')
        self.grid.SetColSize(0,200)
        self.grid.SetColSize(2,200)

    # --
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.grid, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5)
        panel.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
        self.Show()

    def OnKeyPress(self, event):
        uk = event.UnicodeKey
        key = chr(event.UnicodeKey)
        shift = event.shiftDown
        if not shift:
            key = key.lower()
        print("Key", uk, key)
        event.Skip()

    def onEditorCreated(self,event):
        #Set TextCtrl element to want all char/key events for all keys
        self.cb = event.Control
        if event.Control.ClassName == "wxTextCtrl":
            self.cb.SetWindowStyle(wx.WANTS_CHARS) # BEWARE! - Returns Tab, Enter, Arrow keys etc
            self.cb.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN,self.OnKeyPress)
        else:
            print("Non text cell - bailing out")
        event.Skip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyForm()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the effort!
It was very helpful and informative

Comment: Hi,
I have one more question.
When using a regular text control object, one of the functions you can use is 'GetInsertionPoint' that will tell you if the user moved the caret etc. If a grid is made out of many Text controls units, how do I use this insertion function for each cell?

Comment: It's fun to answer myself but I've found the solution for that. You can reach the insertion point via the event itself by: event.EventObject.InsertionPoint.
I'm sure there's a Get function somewhere but that will do.

Comment: @YehudaNOVO Indeed! event.EventObject.GetInsertionPoint()